# How to get the imagesize of DLL from its baseaddress correctly?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, memory-management

I only have the base address of a DLL loaded into memory of another process. I want to get the imagesize of the DLL. So I get MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION from VirtualQuery. This function doesn't fail, but the allocationBase is always 0. The application crashes in the line, where you can read "bug".

Questions: Does VirtualQuery work in the given situation? Is there a better way to get the imagesize? But remember my situation: I want to get the imagesize of a DLL loaded into memory of another process! The DLL isn't loaded into my application, nor do I have a handle to the application at the moment(but it would be possible to get a handle).

```
...
 DWORD baseAddress = (DWORD)me32.modBaseAddr; // base address of a DLL of other process
 MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem;

    if (NULL==VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)baseAddress, &mem, sizeof(mem))) {
        printError( TEXT("VirtualQuery") );
        return false;
    }

    unsigned char* allocationBase = (unsigned char*)mem.AllocationBase;
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n allocationBase = %d"), allocationBase ); // 0

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *dos = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)mem.AllocationBase;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pe = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((unsigned long)
    dos+(unsigned long)dos->e_lfanew); // bug crashes application

size_t base_len = (size_t)pe->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// base address of a DLL of other process
```

The comment says it all, VirtualQuery only returns you info about virtual memory in *your* process, not the process that actually has this DLL loaded.  You'll need to use VirtualQueryEx(), get the required process handle with OpenProcess().